# What and how LLM is used for ranking organization job title?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, large-language-model, nlp-question-answering

Suppose there's a context like this

context = `Andy is a vice manager of finance department. \n Rio is a general manager finance deparment. \n Jason is a general manager finance deparment.`

question = `who is the leader of finance department ?`

what task is this called ?
what model is used ?
how does the model know which title is higher ?
how does the model handle two same data ? (e.g., Rio and Jason)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is a question-answering task. Likely, your model already knows which title is higher based on the training data.

However, since 'Rio' and 'Jason' both hold the same position, it would be difficult to determine who the leader of the finance department is without additional information.

The model might respond by suggesting all possible answers or asking for more information.

Comment: thanks for answering the overall question. However, there's remain one more question: is it possible to determine which one is higher without additional information / training data ? for example Vice president and Director has ambiguity because each companies has difference structure.

the naive way is just to add that information (e.g., Vice manager has higher position then general manager). 

So when someone ask : Who lead the finance department ? the model would like answer the vice manager since it has information that vice manager is higher then general manager

Comment: Well, there is one approach that comes to mind.

Role-Based Questions
By creating a hypothetical organizational structure and posing a question to the model within that scenario, you can encourage the model to interpret the hierarchy of positions based on the given situation.

For instance: "In Company A, the Vice President makes strategic decisions, while the Director handles the execution within departments. In this case, who would hold the higher position in Company A?"

Give it a try~